# JQuery Date Picker Does not work after new Div Created

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a form.

### Script

```
<script>
    // function to add set of elements
    var we = 1;

    function new_workexp() {
    we++;
        var newDiv = $('#workexp div:first').clone();
        newDiv.attr('id', we);
        var delLink = '<a class="btn btn-danger" style="text-align:right;margin-right:65px" href="javascript:delwe(' + we + ')" > Delete Work Experence ' + we + ' </a>';
        newDiv.find('tr:first th').text('workexp ' + we);
        newDiv.append(delLink);
        $('#workexp').append(newDiv);
        newDiv.find('input:text').val('');
    }

    // function to delete the newly added set of elements
    function delwe(eleId) {
        d = document;
        var ele = d.getElementById(eleId);
        var parentEle = d.getElementById('workexp');
        parentEle.removeChild(ele);
    //we--;
    }
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker1({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
        $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker2({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
    });
</script>
```

### HTML

```
<legend>Work Experence</legend>
<div id="workexp">
    <div id="1">
        <br />
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:new_workexp()"> Add New Work Experence </a>
        <br />
        <table border="3">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4" style="background-color:#b0c4de;">Work Experence 1</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>Please Select Your Start Date<input type="text" name="sdate[]" id="datepicker1" class="hasDatepicker"></p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>Please Select Your End Date<input type="text" name="edate[]" id="datepicker2" class="hasDatepicker"></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="ui-datepicker1-div" class="ui-datepicker1 ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>
<div id="ui-datepicker2-div" class="ui-datepicker2 ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>
```

What i am trying to figure out is why when the page loads the datepickers work fine and after i create a new DIV element the datepickers no longer work

When looking at the source i see a class gets added "hasDatepicker" which comes from either the ejquery-ui.js or the sjquery-ui.js which i belive is the culprit.

I have a JSFiddle example however I cannot get the date picker to work.
http://jsfiddle.net/wyyg2avu/1/

Working Example http://thenerdservice.com/add/index.php

Comment: `$(...).datepicker1 is not a function` in the console... Have you added the appropriate plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Solution:

On the page [`thenerdservice.com/add/index.php`](http://thenerdservice.com/add/index.php), go to the following line:

```
newDiv.find('input:text').val('')
```

And simply add:

```
.removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
```

To the end of it. So it looks like:

```
newDiv.find('input:text').val('').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
```

The problem is, you're exactly cloning the previous form, which already has established datepicker inputs in it, thus it can't make new datepickers. Also, you're not calling `.datepicker` on the new inputs anyway, so no events are assigned to the new inputs.

I would recomend rebuilding the form rather than copying it and I would move away from direct ID's on the inputs. It could become confusing.

---

## FURTHER RECOMENDATIONS

I would simplify the whole process and remove the opening form. It's a lot easier if you create `base` template to clone from, then add/remove the parts you need and what not. Also, by making use of `.on` or `.live` you can better control dynamic event tagging to your elements. That is to say, I don't need to make inline `href="function` commands every time. It's easier to just show you what all I mean. [extra links at bottom]

See the following example:


#### jsFiddle

### CSS

```
<style>
    .template { display: none !important; }
    .we-div { margin: 1em auto; }
    .btn-del-we { text-align: right; margin-right:65px }
</style>
```

### JS

```
<script>
    function addDivWE(e) {
        var countWE = $('.we-div:not(.template)').length + 1,
            divWE = $('.template.we-div').clone().removeClass('template').attr({ id: countWE }).appendTo('body')
        divWE.find('.we-count').text(countWE);

        if (countWE > 1) divWE.append($('<a />', { class: 'btn btn-del-we btn-danger', href: 'javascript:void(0)', text: 'Delete Work Experence ' + countWE }));
        divWE.find('input:text').datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
    }

    function delDivWE(e) {
        $(this).closest('.we-div').remove();
        reindexWE();
    }

    function reindexWE() {
        var countWE = $('.we-div:not(.template)').length;
        for (i=0;i<countWE;i++) {
            var divWE = $($('.we-div:not(.template)')[i]),
                newID = i + 1;
            divWE.attr({ id: newID }).find('.we-count').text(newID);
            divWE.find('.btn-del-we').text('Delete Work Experence ' + newID)
        }
    }

    $(document)
        .on('click', '.btn-add-we', addDivWE)
        .on('click', '.btn-del-we', delDivWE)

    addDivWE();
</script>
```

### HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="template we-div">
        <a class="btn btn-add-we btn-info" href="javascript:void(0)"> Add New Work Experence </a>
        <table border="3">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4" style="background-color: #b0c4de;">Work Experence <span class="we-count"></span></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>Please Select Your Start Date<input type="text" name="sdate[]" /></p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>Please Select Your End Date<input type="text" name="edate[]" /></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Follow up information:

- [`.on`/`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [Understand JavaScript Callback Functions and Use Them](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)
- [A Quick Guide to Chaining in jQuery](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect:

```
 $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker1({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
 $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker2({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
```

is the problem, since there is no jQueryUI `datepicker1` or `datepicker2` method

Try

```
  $( "#datepicker1, #datepicker2" ).datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
```

instead

[fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnmux544/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i added a couple lines at the end of the function new_workexp() that seemed to do the trick

```
newDiv.find("#sdate").attr("class", "calendar1");
newDiv.find("#edate").attr("class", "calendar2");
newDiv.find("#sdate").attr("id", "sdate" + we);
newDiv.find("#edate").attr("id", "edate" + we);
newDiv.find(".calendar1").datepicker1({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
newDiv.find(".calendar2").datepicker2({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
```

I changed the static inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="sdate[]" id="sdate" class="calendar1" >
<input type="text" name="edate[]" id="edate" class="calendar2" >
```

Adding a class value to the inputs "calendar1" and calendar2"

The original datepicker function stayed basically the same except looking for a .class and not a #id

```
$(function() {
$('.calendar1').datepicker1({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
$('.calendar2').datepicker2({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
});
```

Once the new_workexp function is executed

It finds the two new text inputs created and assigns a new class "calendar1" removing what the datepicker js put in "calendar1 hasDatepicker".

```
newDiv.find("#sdate").attr("class", "calendar1");
newDiv.find("#edate").attr("class", "calendar2");
```

Then finding those same elements assigns a new id to each increments the last value.

```
newDiv.find("#sdate").attr("id", "sdate" + we);
newDiv.find("#edate").attr("id", "edate" + we);
```

Creating:

```
<input type="text" name="sdate[]" id="sdate1" class="calendar1" >
<input type="text" name="sdate[]" id="edate1" class="calendar2" >
```

Then finally assigns the datepicker function the new inputs.

```
newDiv.find(".calendar1").datepicker1({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
newDiv.find(".calendar2").datepicker2({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
```

To sum up some confusion when i used this on a different project i ran into a problem when adding a range, probably from the same problem i experienced here. To work around that i edited the jquery-ui.js jquery-ui.css files to assign datepicker1 and datepicker2 to each and created 4 new files.

```
sjquery-ui.js
sjquery-ui.css
ejquery-ui.js
ejquery-ui.css
```

Im sure i could have condensed this further however it is working for now.

Comment: did you even half look at my answer? I had completely fixed your original problem and showed you how to condense your code. And it's pretty easy to read. I can add more comments of information if it's not easy enough for you?